# Multilevel database query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a complicated question about Laravel. I have 3 tables; "orders", "order_packages", and "order_line_articles".

Each order ("orders" table) consists of packages ("order_packages" table) and those packages contain articles ("order_line_articles" table). Some of them have a more specific choice such as a measure (column "choice_id"). Each article can also have a different supplier, and those suppliers all have a different way of handling.

What I want is all orders for which "order_line_articles" have not yet been delivered ("settled" column). But then only the articles for which the supplier has (for example) ID 1 as its handling. I also want the following information; order, item and possibly information of the choice (for example size) if it is needed.

Part of the DB structure below:

```
orders --> Model "Order"
------------
id
code_id (not relevant for now)
customer_id



order_lines --> Model "OrderLines"
------------
id
order_id
package_id (not relevant for now)



order_line_articles --> Model "OrderLineArticle"
------------
id
order_line_id
package_id (not relevant for now)
article_id
choice_id
settled



articles --> Model "Article"
------------
id
name
supplier_id
(and some more but not relevant)



suppliers --> Model "Supplier"
------------
id
name
handling_id
```

It is a rather complicated construction, but I hope someone can help me build the right query while maintaining relationships.

Comment: i suggest sticking to the Laravel query builder, you can't always use relationships for complex / big queries.

Comment: But i can't access my model relations then

Comment: You could hydrate the article model so you can use the relationships after you retrieved the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the difference between order_line and order_line_article tables, but either way, why can't you achieve this with Laravel's Relationships?

E.g.

Order.php

```
// one Order has many OrderLines
public function orderLines() { return $this->hasMany('\App\OrderLine'); }
```

OrderLine.php

```
// one OrderLine has many OrderLineArticles
public function order() { return $this->belongsTo('\App\Order'); }
public function orderLineArticles() { return $this->hasMany('\App\OrderLineArticle'); }
```

OrderLineArticle.php

```
// one OrderLineArticle belongs to an Article
public function orderLine() { return $this->belongsTo('\App\OrderLine'); }
public function article() { return $this->belongsTo('\App\Article'); }
```

Article.php

```
// an Article has many OrderlineArticles
public function orderLineArticles() { return $this->hasMany('\App\OrderLineArticle'); }
```

Query:

```
Order::with('orderlines.orderlinearticles.article')->get()->where('orderlines.orderlinearticles.settled','no')->where('orderlines.orderlinearticles.article.supplier_id',69)->get()
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks for ur answer, but i dont get this working. I'll show you my situation now.

Comment: Order.php
`public function lines() { return $this->hasMany('App\OrderLine', 'order_id');}` 

OrderLine.php
`public function order() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'order_id', 'id');}
public function articles() { return $this->hasMany('App\OrderLineArticle', 'order_line_id', 'id');}`

OrderLineArticle.php
`public function line() { return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderLine', 'order_line_id', 'id'); }
public function article() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Article', 'article_id', 'id');}`


Article.php
`public function lines() { return $this->hasMany('App\OrderLineArticle');}`

Comment: Query:
`$orders = Order::with('lines.articles.article')
            ->whereNull('lines.articles.article.settled')
            ->where('lines.articles.article.supplier.handling_id', '=', '1')->get();`

Dumped query:
`select * from `orders` where `lines`.`articles`.`article`.`settled` is null and `lines`.`articles`.`article`.`supplier`.`handling_id` = ? and `orders`.`deleted_at` is null`

Comment: This is the error i got:
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`settled` is null and `lines`.`articles`.`article`.`supplier`.`handling_id` = ?' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `orders` where `lines`.`articles`.`article`.`settled` is null and `lines`.`articles`.`article`.`supplier`.`handling_id` = 1 and `orders`.`deleted_at` is null)`

Comment: Hi Martijn, please could you add the code into your post above rather than pasting into the comments!

Comment: Also, you can see the query being generated is wrong. so try dumping the results of `Order::with('lines.articles.article')->get()` and then you can use collection functions to filter the result.